# Fix the upstream dependency conflict while creating new angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, npm-install

**Version:** 
Angular CLI: 12.1.1 
Node: 14.17.3 
Package Manager: npm 7.19.1

Error coming while creating a new angular project.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-beginner@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.7.1
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.7.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.8" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

After searching StackOverflow I found this and tried.

1. Run the command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
2. npm uninstall –g @angular/CLI 
   npm cache clean --force 
   npm install –g @angular/cli@latest

But still didn't resolve the issue. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

npm version 7 has some issues. I have downgraded the npm version to 6.
It's running now.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it downgrading my `node` and `npm` versions, it seems that the problem is with `npm 7`.

```
Angular CLI: 12.1.1
Node: 14.16.1
Package Manager: npm 6.14.12
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this worked

```
npm audit fix --force
```

Then try again